# retrieving sub key from a nested dictionary using python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, parsing

I have this dictionary, where I would like to retrieve the value of 'id'.
What would be the best way?

```
dict = {'total': 2, 'page': 0, 'pageSize': 10, 'count': 2, 'results': [{'id': 3, 'domainId': 1}]}
```

I have tried:

> ```
>       print (dict['id'])
> ```
>
> E           KeyError: 'id'

if I print the keys, I only get:

```
['total', 'page', 'pageSize', 'count', 'results']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, don't call your variable `dict` as that is the name of the Python type of a dictionary, so you're currently overwriting that function.

Let's call it `d` instead.

```
d = {
  'total': 2, 
  'page': 0, 
  'pageSize': 10, 
  'count': 2, 
  'results': [
    {'id': 3, 'domainId': 1}
  ]
}
```

Here we can see that `d['results']` is what we want to query for the id. It's a list, so I would question whether you're always going to want the first thing or all of the things or just the last thing.

If it were me, I would first extract all ids, and then get the one I actually wanted.

We can get all ids as a list with:

```
[r['id'] for r in d['results'] if 'id' in r]
```

That means that if `results` was the following list, we'd get the following ids:

```
d['results'] == [
  {'id': 3, 'domainId': 1},
  {'id': 4},
  {'domainId': 2},
  {'giraffe': True}
]

ids = [r['id'] for r in d['results'] if 'id' in r]

ids == [3, 4]
```

At this point we could process all ids, or just get the first (`ids[0]`) or the last (`ids[-1]`).

---

If you know exactly which index it's going to be in `results`, you could access that directly.

```
d['results'][-1]['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

`id_value = dict['results'][0]['id']`

Also, you generally shouldn't call your dictionaries `dict` in Python. `dict` is the name of a built-in function, and you might mess things up by overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

`dict['results'][0]['id']` gets that value. Having the nested dictionary in a list convolutes things a bit.

Comment: and what if I want to retrieve all 'id' values in case I have multiple? I mean: what if I have: d = {'total': 2, 'page': 0, 'pageSize': 10, 'count': 2, 'results': [{'id': 3, 'domainId': 1},{'id': 4, 'domainId': 1}]}. how do I retrieve the values 3,4 from here?

Comment: `dict['results'][0]['id'], dict['results'][1]['id']`. I would advise against storing data like this as it isn't a very clear way of retrieving it. Maybe a class or a pandas DataFrame would be more suited?

Comment: and what is the best way to use instead of [0] and [1] while knowing the amount of objects I would like to retrieve? meaning, I know the count is 2 in this case, but I can't just do [1] and [2] as I would need in this case, use [0] and [1]. would it be a for loop starting from 0 until [count-1] be the best way?

Comment: `[x['id'] for x in dict['results'][:count]]` could be an option. But again I would try and rethink your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `'results'` is a list whose first item is another dictionary. You can access the nested dictionary with index 0.

```
print(dict['results'][0]['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value = dict['results'][0]['id']
```

You use the `dict['results']` to access the list in which the first element `[0]` that is a dictionary in which you can finally get the value of `[id]` .